# python - How to find the image of an array x1 with a curve made with array (x,y)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Thanks to whoever is reading this question.

I have a plot (from two same-sized arrays: x and y).
I have another array x1 and want to find the corresponding array y1 by the same plotted function.

Mathematically, this would give:
I have f(x)=y (x and y are two arrays)
I want to find f(x1) (same f, different x).

This is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y_vek = []
x = np.linspace (0,1,20)
y = [0,3,4,5,7,6,34,3,42,53,5,57,67,67,5,67,65,21,6,0] 

plt.plot (x,y,'g',label='y')
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

In my case, f is defined by the arrays x and y.
Now I have an x1 different from x (same-sized with x) and want to find f(x1).

Is there a way to find that?

Comment: But you don't know the function `f`, correct?

Comment: Sounds like your best option is to use (linear) interpolation, for example with [`numpy.interp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html).

Comment: Yes, I don´t know the function y. I will check numpy.interp, thanks.